# Font Awesome not displaying in IE 10

Tags: font-face, font-awesome

is there any general reason for which Font Awesome doesn't show up in IE 10?

Another question - what's the @font-face thing all about? Do I have to use it? I haven't done it so far and it works well in Firefox and Chrome, could that be the reason for IE?

(excuse my ignorance, I'm a complete newbie)

Comment: Do you have that font installed on user machine?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question (newbie, like I said :) ) Can you try to explain?

Comment: I too am having the issue described by oneday, and I can verify that it occurs regardless of compatibility mode settings. For me, it occurs only in IE10, not IE9 or IE11.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, the actual cause was https secured connection

I was using https protocol changed it to http

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I Hope it helps

Comment: This "solved" the problem with displaying font awesome for me, but i need the site to have a secure connection so not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is working on other browsers, make sure you are not in compatibility mode or have not accidentally put your site on the compatibility list in IE.

If it doesn't work in others, it has to have 2 classes: `fa` AND `fa-blah` (assuming Font Awesome 4.x; Font Awesome 3.x has different notation)

Also, check your developer tools `F12` to make sure all the fonts and CSS/JS is loading into the site.

Comment: You have to include those font files in the site and make sure they are loaded because those font files actually contain the icons.  If it's specific to IE, I suspect something with Compatibility Settings.

Comment: I see now that font-awesome.js contains @font-face, so ingnore this part (unless there's more to be done about it). If it comes to compatibility mode, it seems to be off - only the intranet checkbox is checked, "display all websites in compatibility mode" (or however it's put in English) is off. Any other ideas?

Comment: (1) You want to be sure Compatibility Mode is OFF.  (2) I have seen some issues where the relative directory structure they assume is not correct (like a /fonts directory at the same level as your CSS directory).  But, this would show up as 404s if you used the Network tab in your developer tools to verify all the files are getting loaded.  I've had to edit some of the Font Awesome source files to match my site because I use ASP.NET MVC which has its own structure that the project comes with.

Comment: (1) Yes, I assume it's off from what I see
(2) I understand commas and periods from what you just said... Woke up one day with the idea of becoming a web designer, why not a truck driver? Ok, let's risk another newbie question - how do I enter the Developer Tools on IE?

Comment: F12, Network tab, refresh the page.  Web Designers need to have a strong grasp on how to debug pages in all browsers, so it would be a good idea to research debugging tools in each browser.